# enmaps get deleted upon restarts

Tags: javascript, discord.js

my enmaps gets deleted once my discord bot gets restarted
this is how I simply store data

```
const Enmap = require("enmap");
client.points = new Enmap();
client.points.set("test", "works?")
```

and it gets deleted when the discord bot restarts if this is normal is there a way to prevent that and to actually save the data?

Comment: You will need to synchronize with a database

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your enmap a name for persistent storage. Try something like:

```
client.points = new Enmap({
    name: "points"
});
```

You also need access to the filesystem, so if you're hosting your bot on Heroku enmap won't work. Take a look at the [official documentation](https://enmap.evie.dev/usage) for enmap for more info on how to use it.

Comment: well that doesn't work either oh and I'm hosting my bot locally and just using a normal powershell